# ModuleNotFoundError in Python while importing module from another folder

Tags: python, coding-style

I am trying to structure Python project with different modules and having the test script for each module. My project directory looks something as shown below:

```
├── project
│   ├── main.py
├── F1
│   ├── add.py
|   └── prin_add.py
```

***main.py***

```
from f1.add import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    add(4,5)
```

***add.py***

```
from print_add import *
def add(a,b):
    print_add(a+b)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    add(4,5)
```

***print_add.py***

```
def print_add(c):
    print(f'sum = {c}')
```

If I run the main.py, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'print_add'`. I think this is due to the absolute and relative path of the modules. How can I have the modules imported using a relative path? If I use something like `from .print_add import *` in ***add.py*** file, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.print_add'; '__main__' is not a package` while running add.py file.

What is the best practice to structure Python modules? I am using Python 3.6 and I don't think I need to have **init**.py file.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/714647/8089674

Comment: you need to use a relative import here rather than an absolute import